# Flutter : Sending Email

Tags: flutter, dart

i want little ask about sending email with flutter . I using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender#-readme-tab- for sending email.

#### Sending Function

```
Future sendEmail(String subject,String body,List<String> recipients) async{
    final Email email = Email(body: body,subject: subject,recipients: recipients);
    String platformResponse;
    try {
      await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
      platformResponse='success';
    } catch (e) {
      platformResponse = e.toString(); 
    }
    print(platformResponse);
  }
```

View.dart

```
Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => _sendMail(),
    child: Text('send'),
  ),
)
void _sendMail() async {
    return await api.sendEmail(widget.namaUpdate, widget.jurusanUpdate,['zefry.reynando@gmail.com']);
  }
```

it's possible sending email automatic without open gmail app first ? (Like in codeigniter)

i trying using another package but always open gmail app first. or this how it works?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you send the information over to a server and send the email from there ?.

Comment: use - https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

Comment: @SaifKamaal i'm thinking about it, i think in flutter can be automatic, i'm new in sending email using flutter

Comment: @anmol.majhail i will learn about this package, thank's for the suggest.

Comment: @anmol.majhail i'm confused about configuration SMTP , how can i config this SMTP ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando - Choose the SMTP Provider first then google - their SMTP config setting - use that in `mailer` - E.g - Gmail - search Gmail Smtp settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not likely to find a package that sends email out without either configuration or a visible mail client.  That app would not by approved by either Apple or Google, because it might be a source of SPAM.